# Oracle referenciar o tipo de uma coluna igual ao tipo de outra coluna

Tags: oracle, funções, pl-sql

Estou tentando criar uma *table* para retornar em uma função. Para isso, estou tentando criar um `object type` dessa forma:

```
create or replace type relatorio as object (
  planta TABLE_NAME.COLUMN%TYPE,
  resp_0 TABLE_NAME.COLUMN%TYPE
);
```

Porém está retornando o erro:

> PSL-00201:o identificador 'TABLE_NAME.COLUMN' deve ser declarado

A minha pergunta é: estou usando o `%TYPE` de maneira adequada?

Comment: E o que esta sendo colocado em table_name.column?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta Reginaldo?

Comment: Como é o comando que esta indo para o banco?

Comment: De fato eu nunca vi esse comando para a criação de tabelas, nem sei se é possivel. Ele é usado em TRIGGERS ou PROCEDURES para você criar variaveis. Você cria a variavel 'planta' com o mesmo tipo e tamanho da coluna do banco.

Comment: Isso msm Reginaldo, eu estou tentando fazer uma função para retornar uma tabela, só que a tabela não existe no banco, portanto teria que criar uma tabela nova.
Procurando na internet  encontre esse exemplo [link](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html)

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo e deve entender como utilizar.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE (
   ID INTEGER,
   CAMPO_T VACHAR(20))
```

Na PROCEDURE ou TRIGGER você faria isso:

```
DECLARE
    v_texto TESTE.CAMPO_T%TYPE;
```

Mesmo que mude o tamanho do campo na tabela a sua procedure continua válida.

Poderia ser usada para criar uma váriavel com base em uma outra já declarada.

```
 DECLARE
 v1 VARCHAR2(13) := 'bla bla bla';
 v2 v1%TYPE := UPPER(v1);
 v3 v1%TYPE := LOWER(v2);
```

Comment: Entendi, mas como seria para retornar essa tabela em uma função(FUNCTION)?

Comment: Como é isso? Não entendi o que você quer fazer, de onde você chamaria essa função e o que ela devolveria.

Comment: Se a tabela não existe não tem como você se referenciar aos campos dela. Quando você diz ´v_texto TESTE.CAMPO_T%TYPE;´ Você quer dizer que a variável v_texto é do mesmo tipo e tamanho do ´CAMPO_T´ da tabela ´TESTE´

Comment: Bom vou tentar me explicar melhor.

Estou fazendo uma função no meu banco de dados para buscar dados em uma tabela e ordenar de uma maneira adequada, dai eu retorno para aplicação esses dados no formato adequado.

Portanto preciso de uma tabela "temporária" para colocar os dados da consulta na tabela original e retorno essa tabela "temporária" para aplicação com os dados no formato correto.

Estou fazendo isso para simplificar o código na aplicação.

Comment: Você poderia fazer algo assim: CREATE TABLE TEMPORARIA AS SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABELA

Answer (score 0):

Segue abaixo uma solução. Para simplificar considerei que a sua função relatório retornaria uma tabela com os campos **nome** e **quantidade**.

Link da solução funcionando no SQL Feedle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c06c/1/0

1) Criar um tipo **object** que contém uma representação das colunas da tabela a ser retornada pela sua função.

```
    create or replace type t_linhas as object (
      nome varchar2(30),
      quantidade number
    );
    /
```

2) Criar um tipo **table**. Observe abaixo que a tabela é formada pelo tipo **t_linhas** que acabou de ser criado.

```
    create or replace type t_tabela_relatorio as table of t_linhas;
    /
```

3) Criar a função retornando o tipo **t_tabela_relatorio** que foi criado no inicio

```
    create or replace function fc_relatorio return t_tabela_relatorio as
      v_ret   t_tabela_relatorio;

      cursor c_consulta_base_relatorio is
      select 'Joao' as nome_cliente, 10 as qtd from dual union
      select 'Pedro' as nome_cilente, 20 as qtd from dual union
      select 'Isabel' as nome_ciente, 15 as qtd from dual;

    begin
      v_ret  := t_tabela_relatorio();          

      for x in c_consulta_base_relatorio loop    
        v_ret.extend;
        v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_linhas(x.nome_cliente,x.qtd);
      end loop;
      return v_ret;
    end fc_relatorio;
    /
```

3) Exemplo de como chamar a função:

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(FC_RELATORIO())
```

Fonte: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html